# How can I filter only registered users in drupal?

Tags: drupal

I can filter users lie administrators, redaktors, editors, but I cannot filter registered users.
Is there a module for it?
I cannot find anything!

I just wnat to see list of registered users except administrators, editors,corectors ...you know.
thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create a View of type `Users` (and NOT `Node` like it usually is). Now add a filter. Choose the `Users` group in the filters drop down. Choose `User: Roles` filter. Set the operator to `is none of` and select editor, corrector etc. check boxes. This way you will ONLY see registered users on your site.

(BTW you can always expose this filter to have control on what roles you want to see/not want to see listed)

**Additional Question: How to count users**

Enable the PHP Filter module, add the following in the header of the view (with input format selected as PHP Filter) and insert the following code:

```
<?php
  $view = views_get_current_view();
  print count($view->result)." Users";
?>
```

Comment: @perfectDay: See my answer to see how to count users.

Comment: BTW PHP Filter comes with every Drupal installation. You don't need to download it separately